# Unable to Parse response as JSON error Symfony

Tags: php, json, rest, symfony, httpful

I have a controller that sends a get request and then tries to parse the response as a JSON. However, requesting it through the browser returns a valid JSON object. I'm getting a 500 error that says 'Exception: Unable to parse response as JSON' and points to `JsonHandler.php` in the `Httpful` library. I looked through the file and it is because the body is empty. 
I am confused since the request url is valid and returns a valid JSON object.

`Controller.php`

```
        Authorization::checkUser();
        $request = $this->request;

        $callback = $request->query->get('callback');
        $url = 'http://example.com/api/get_recent_posts/?' . http_build_query(
            [
                'count'     => 20,
                'post_type' => 'schedule_show',
                'page'      => (int) $request->query->get('page', 1),
                'order'     => 'ASC',
                'orderby'   => 'title',
                'include'   => 'id,title',
                '_'         => (int) $request->query->get('_', time()),
            ]
        );

        /** @var \Httpful\Response $APIResponse */

        $APIResponse = \Httpful\Request::get($url, 'application/json')->send();
        $data = $APIResponse->body;
        $response = new JsonResponse($data);

        $response->setCallback($callback);

        return $response;
```

JSON Response:

```
     {  
   "status":"ok",
   "count":20,
   "count_total":70,
   "pages":4,
   "posts":[  
      {  
         "id":2473,
         "title":"ACOUSTIC ROOTS"
      },
      {  
         "id":2531,
         "title":"AFRIKA REVISITED"
      },
      {  
         "id":2542,
         "title":"AMANECER RANCHERO"
      },
      {  
         "id":2551,
         "title":"APNIVANI"
      },
      {  
         "id":2504,
         "title":"APT 613 LIVE"
      },
      {  
         "id":6229,
         "title":"ATMOSPHERE"
      },
      {  
         "id":2532,
         "title":"BLACK ON BLACK"
      },
      {  
         "id":2550,
         "title":"BOUYON RASIN"
      },
      {  
         "id":2462,
         "title":"CAN-ROCK"
      },
      {  
         "id":2534,
         "title":"CARIBBEAN FLAVOUR"
      },
      {  
         "id":5288,
         "title":"CHUO TOP 30"
      },
      {  
         "id":6060,
         "title":"CINEMASCOPE"
      },
      {  
         "id":2930,
         "title":"CITY SLANG"
      },
      {  
         "id":2524,
         "title":"CYPHER"
      },
      {  
         "id":2484,
         "title":"D&#8217;UN EXTR\u00caME \u00c0 L&#8217;AUTRE"
      },
      {  
         "id":2478,
         "title":"DEMOCKERY&#8217;S DEMISE"
      },
      {  
         "id":2438,
         "title":"DEMOCRACY NOW!"
      },
      {  
         "id":2546,
         "title":"ETHIOPIAN SHOW"
      },
      {  
         "id":5930,
         "title":"FREESTYLE"
      },
      {  
         "id":6247,
         "title":"FR\u00c9QUENCE ANTILLAISE"
      }
   ]
}
```

The AJAX request:

```
$.ajax('/shows/select/load', {
  data: {
    count: 20,
    post_type: 'schedule_show',
    page: this.page_current,
    order: 'ASC',
    orderby: 'title',
    include: 'id,title'
  },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  context: this,
  success: this.loadShows
});
```

Am I missing something?

Edit: 
Method that tries to parse the body and throws the exception.

JsonHandler.php:

```
public function parse($body)
    {
        $body = $this->stripBom($body);
        if (empty($body))
            return null;
        $parsed = json_decode($body, $this->decode_as_array);
        if (is_null($parsed) && 'null' !== strtolower($body))
            throw new \Exception("Unable to parse response as JSON");
        return $parsed;
    }
```

For debugging purposes I added these var_dump statements:

```
public function parse($body)
    {
        var_dump($body);
        $body = $this->stripBom($body);
        var_dump($body);
        if (empty($body))
            return null;
        var_dump($this->decode_as_array);
        $parsed = json_decode($body, $this->decode_as_array);
        var_dump($parsed);
        if (is_null($parsed) && 'null' !== strtolower($body))
            throw new \Exception("Unable to parse response as JSON");
        return $parsed;
    }
```

This returned:

```
string(1) " " 
string(1) " " 
bool(false) 
NULL
```

Comment: Your json looks good in formatting and would be parsed correct.
However check your stripBom function, what does that do?

Comment: @Archi I checked the argument `$body` before it's passed to `stripBom` in `JsonHandler.php` and it is a string with one space `' '`. So `stripBom` doesn't really cause the issue here. Not for now at least.

Comment: This is the debugging thing. I tried putting the JSON you have provided as it is in the $body variable and then tried json_decode($body, true) and json_decode($body, false) functions and they would parse json correct. It won't be null. 

i would suggest dump out the $body after stripBom, dump $this->decode_as_array and find out whether it's true, false, null ? And then finally dump the $parsed value and see what's happening.

Comment: @Archi Okay I will try that, I'll get back to you in around an hour.

Comment: @Archi Check my latest edit.

Comment: So... Your received body is empty.

Comment: @Veve Yes, but it shouldn't be since the request generates a valid JSON response, why isn't that getting passed as the body.

Comment: What is success: this.loadShows ? Where are you calling the parse method of JsonHandler.php file?

Again I would say this is the debugging question!!

Comment: loadShows is the functions that runs and uses the response and puts it into an HTML table. The parse method is called by a class called `Response.php` which calls the appropriate parse method depending on the mime type of the response.

Comment: I can post all the methods in between the request and JsonHandler if necessary as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `Request.php` in the function `send`. The method uses curl and after checking the response after `curl_exec` it was returning a 301 code with an empty body. All I had to do was set a new curl option `curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` And it worked fine.